# PDO: Check if user entered correct database info (install script)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on an installation script for my project. Basicly what I would like to do is check if the user entered the correct Database information, and if not, return an error. This is what I've tried to accomplish this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

require "classes/pdo.class.php";

// Define configuration
define("DB_HOST", $_POST['db_host']);
define("DB_USER", $_POST['db_name']);
define("DB_PASS", $_POST['db_user']);
define("DB_NAME", $_POST['db_pass']);

try {
    $db = new Database();
    echo "Succes!";
} catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo "Failed!";
}

?>
```

Unfortunetely, this always returns a Succes! Even when the user entered data is incorrect. Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to use a different approach?

Here's the code I'm using for my PDO class:

```
<?php

Class Database {
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    private $stmt;

    public function __construct(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function column(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }

    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function rowCount(){
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function beginTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }

    public function endTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->commit();
    }

    public function cancelTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->rollBack();
    }

    public function debugDumpParams(){
        return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You set `$this->error` in the construct. Why you don't check this?

Comment: Yes I've figured that out. Stupid mistake on my side! Thanks. Will mark as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your getting success every time is because the DB object is created regardless of whether or not the connection is successful.

You should just try to connect and if it fails, then you know the creds are wrong.   You can run this in your code,  or create a method in your DB class to check this and return true or false.  (Or I guess you could modify the constructor to throw an exception, but I don't think that's the right way to go)

```
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
        try{
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: That's what the class is doing. Take a look at the `__construct` :)

Comment: Dude, relax. I appreciate your help. I'm just pointing out that the constructor already tries the connection if I'm not mistaken. I could be wrong though. So I'm trying to figure that out. That's all

Comment: OK sorry,  my bad.  The object is constructed no matter what.   If connection fails it doesn't matter.     That's why you either need to try the connection in your code,  or you can add a method to the class that checks the connection and returns true or false.   instanciating an object will not give you the information you need.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working :) Will mark yours as answered as soon as I can :)

Comment: Personally, I would let the constructor throw an exception. If you're trying trying to instantiate a database object, but you can't connect then it's a pretty exceptional circumstance, not to mention the idea of a valid object being returned for an invalid connection just sounds...bad. But maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if an exception is thrown, it's caught in the constructor. Looks like the constructor doesn't throw an exception.

The caller won't "see" the exception, because it's being "swallowed" in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I think I should point out that this bad design to do stuff inside constructors.

I would go somthing like this :

```
function createDbh() 
{    
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    return new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
}

function createDatabase()
{
    return new Database(createDbh());
}
```

And in your bootstrap :

```
try {
    $db = createDatabase();
} catch(Exception $ex){
    echo "Failed!";
}
```

This way, **when** you'll write your unit test for the `Database` class, it will be easy to inject a mock object

Comment: Wait, so you abstract the creation of the PDO object to another function, but then use the concrete PDOException type hint for the exception handling? I really don't see this as better design tbh. Feels very forced. Also, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I've changed the catch part althought it doesn't really matter imo. And yes i answer the question... With this code you get into the catch when the connection fails.

Comment: I've checked yours and it's certainly working just fine aswell. Upvoted because imo that downvote isn't fair for a working solution.